# Closing an SQLiteAsyncConnection

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net

I am using the sqlite-net-pcl library in my Xamarin Android project ([the one by Frank Krueger](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), not [this fork by Øystein Krog](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL)). It seems that as of now, the SQLiteAsyncConnection does not have a Close or Dispose method [according to the author](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/101).

I have two questions. First, would using the connection as a singleton conserve resources? Second can I use sqliteAsyncConnection.GetConnection().Close() to close a connection?

I plan to do something like:

```
public static async Task CloseDbConnectionAsync(SQLiteAsyncConnection dbConnection)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dbConnection.GetConnection().Close());
}
```

Comment: The sqlite-net-pcl owner has answered the question [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/480).

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Yes, the author was kind enough to respond me. Please see my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question in two parts:

**a)** Would using the [SQlite database] connection as a singleton conserve resources?

Yes, according to [this article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html), making your database instance a singleton instance across the entire application’s life cycle can prevent you from opening too many connections and forgetting to close them.

This is how I implemented it in C#:

```
private static SQLiteAsyncConnection _conn;
private static readonly AsyncLock _mutex = new AsyncLock();

private static async Task<SQLiteAsyncConnection> GetDb(Context context)
{
    try
    {
        using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
        {
            if (_conn != null)
            {
                return _conn;
            }

            _conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(GetDbPath(context), storeDateTimeAsTicks: false);

            return _conn;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The AsycnLock is part of the Nito.AsyncEx library.

**b)** Second can I use sqliteAsyncConnection.GetConnection().Close() to close a connection?

The author of the library has responded me [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/480).
This is currently what my disposing method looks like (though I'm not using it anywhere).

```
private static async Task DisposeDbConnectionAsync()
{
    using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
    {
        if (_conn == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            _conn.GetConnection().Close();
            _conn.GetConnection().Dispose();
            _conn = null;

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        });
    }
}
```

The reason I'm calling the GC is because I am not sure that the dispose method  releases the connection immediately or until the GC runs.